# Track all macro calls inside input .tex file (via luatex?)

Tags: luatex, lthooks

If we have an input .tex file, how to find all macro invocations in it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\samplemacro}{This is a sample macro.}

\begin{document}
\samplemacro

\begin{itemize}
    \item \samplemacro
\end{itemize}
\section[\samplemacro]{\samplemacro}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Any kind of position would be fine, e.g. a byte offset for start/end of the command. Start is when the command would start being processed, while end is just after all arguments have been consumed.

For the example above, would be great to get it as follows:

```json
[
  '\documentclass{article}',
  '\newcommand{\samplemacro}{This is a sample macro.}',

  '\begin{document}',
  '\samplemacro',

  '\begin{itemize}',
  '\item'
  '\samplemacro',
  '\end{itemize}',
  ['\section[\samplemacro]{\samplemacro}', '\samplemacro', '\samplemacro'],
  '\tableofcontents',
  '\end{document}'
]
```

The exact structure is not really important, so it is ok to consider \samplemacro to be just a part of \section without tracing the internal calls, or maybe considering the environment content to be the part of \begin. It is literally about what tokens are consumed by which routine.

Since macros like `\section` implement custom parsing, it seems much easier to somehow use luatex hooks than hardcoding parsing like [TexSoup](https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup) is trying to do.

Comment: `\tracingmacros=1` ?

Comment: your result is not well defined. `\section` for example has no arguments at the tex level, you are parsing it as if it has two arguments `\section[\samplemacro]{\samplemacro}` which is as it is documented and in simple cases clear enough, but in other cases it isn't clear how you would define "arguments" of the document command.

Comment: for example you parse `\begin` as one argument `\begin{itemize}`  but how would you parse `\begin{itemize}[label=\alph*]` the optional argument can't really be called an argument of `\begin`

Comment: tracingmacros seemingly does not allow to separate internal calls from the primary ones

Comment: I am thinking about that from programming standpoint: Luatex engine should know which code it is executing. And as I mention, \section is a great example. It consumes some part of input internally, so the next token after it is done should be the end of that call, irrespective of how much was consumed.

Comment: Same with itemize - there is a token which is not consumed by the macro call resulting from \begin expansion, which can be considered the end of that command

Comment: "tracingmacros seemingly does not allow to separate internal calls from the primary ones"  that distinction really doesn't exist: it's a figment of beginner documentation omitting details in a macro expansion language  there is no function call stack as there is in a compiled language, there really is no real notion that corresponds to the documented arguments of a function such as `\section`

Comment: Terribly difficult. As far as I know, even LuaTeX doesn't provide support at this level. Basically you have 2 routes ● learn how TeX works in the internal level (TeXbook → LaTeX companion), learn how the TeX engine work (`texdoc tex` and/or read LuaTeX source code), patch it to output whatever you want, or ● use an external parser that handles most special cases. (refer to e.g. pandoc, TeXsoup).

Comment: It still should be possible to trace the origin of tokens somehow… but looks like not via standard engine.

Comment: TexSoup is what I tried to use, but in fact it does not work as soon as there is a catcode change or some non-standard command to parse